# Array of Strings does not show data on form

Tags: jquery, alpacajs

I have the following form that I have been battling with for some time and cannot figure out why the data is not displaying.

The form renders the correct number of array elements, but the values are not displayed.

Any hint or suggestion on how to try and fix it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flow1Input2Parameter Form</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.23/bootstrap/alpaca.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.23/bootstrap/alpaca.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.14.30/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <style>
body {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75, 0.75); /* Moz-browsers */ 
    zoom: 0.75; /* Other non-webkit browsers */ 
    zoom: 75%; /* Webkit browsers */ 
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="field1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Alpaca.logLevel = Alpaca.DEBUG;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#field1").alpaca({
            "view": "bootstrap-create",
            "data": '{ "strs" : [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]}',
            "schema" : {
                "title" : "Object",
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "strs" : {
                        "title" : "Integers3",
                        "type": "array",
                        "items" : {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }   
                }
            },
            "options" : { 
                "fields" : {
                    "strs" : {
                        "fields" : {
                            "item" : {
                                "size" : 5      
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "form" : {
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Alpaca. Is it possible to create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Thanks so much. Here is a full HTML page including all Alpaca form dependencies with the specific Alpaca form definition language. Appreciate you reviewing and checking this out.

Comment: I just updated the description with a full small sample to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited it to streamline it a bit but I still do not see where the GENERATED HTML is. You have your code but could you perhaps do a chunk of the output? Or is this it?

Comment: This is the code. Alpaca will generate dynamically the form. So even if you do a view source on the page in the browser, you will not get the generated HTML code.

Comment: I finally figure out what the problem was. It has to do with the view value setting. as I am setting it to "bootstrap-create", it is overwriting any existing value as it is assuming a form for initial data entry. If you delete the "view" line or change the assigned value to "bootstrap-update", then all values are shown correctly.